# Action method not being called while calling from window.open() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I am trying to open a new window and call an action in the process in struts 2.

The problem is the jsp opens but the action is not being called till i press refresh or go from the new jsp.

I want the action to execute and then redirect to the corresponding jsp but right now it redirects to the jsp corresponding to the first mapped result.

**action call from javascript:**

```
function displayGraph(graphName)
        {   alert("displayGraph");
            var url = 'drawCMGraph?data=' + encodeURIComponent(graphName);
            alert(url);
            window.open(url, "_blank",
            "directories=no, status=no,width=550, height=200,top=0,left=0");
        }
```

**action mapping in struts.xml**

```
<action name="drawCMGraph" class="com.casealerts.action.HomeAction" method="Drawgraph">
<result name="success">/casealerts/test.jsp</result>
<result name="error">/casealerts/Error.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Comp</display-name>
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
     <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>  <!--This listener handles caching of data when the server context is loaded.-->
        <listener-class>CompListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/casealerts/Login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**action**

```
package com.casealerts.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;
import com.casealerts.businessdelegate.HomePageCMDelegate;
import com.casealerts.formbean.HomeForm;



public class HomeAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<HomeForm>,Preparable,ServletRequestAware
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 272240572969090988L;
    Logger log=new Log4jHelper().getLogger(getClass());
    HomeDelegate hpd=null;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    HomeForm form=null;
    private HttpSession session=null;

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.request=request;

    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        form=new HomeForm();

    }

    @Override
    public HomeForm getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return form;
    }

    public String Drawgraph()
    {
        session=request.getSession(true);
        hpd=new HomeDelegate(form,session);

        String result=hpd.getGraphData("alert", 1);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Action and the web.xml configuration. P.S: The method should start with a lowercase 'D'...

Comment: Use `<s:url>` tag in your javascript.

Comment: @Aleksandr M  could u please eloberate.

Comment: any exception coming on the server console...

Comment: @panky1986 no exception on server console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. It seems we need to create a variable and getter and setter for the data being sent in the URL in the action class. 
This works fine for IE but  it doesn't work in eclipse browser

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'drawCMGraph?data=' + encodeURIComponent(graphName);
            alert(url);
```

try changing it to

```
var url = 'drawCMGraph.action?data=' + encodeURIComponent(graphName);
            alert(url);
```